# Unable to load the Rich Page Editor in Worklight Studio 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm using Worklight Studio version 7.1 on Juno Eclipse 4.2.2 - and the Rich Page Editor fails to load when any index.html file is opened.

See screen-shot image (I couldn't post it here, so its on Dropbox)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c49l78l7w6s42b5/worklight-studio.png?dl=0

I was able to load the RPE in Worklight 7.0 and earlier versions with the same exact eclipse version. Not sure what is so different with Worklight 7.1

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mac, this works for me in a new project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLOt.png.

Does this fail for you with a new project or existing project?
You can use Eclipse Kepler, Luna or Mars instead as an alternative to Eclipse Juno. Or at least check if it fails there as well.

Comment: Fails with a new MobileFirst project. Also tried Juno eclipse 32-bit ... and the same issue is observed. Will try with Kepler or Luna eclipse environment